# "Should have been" in Future II and Past

Tags: grammar, tenses, future-perfect

I'm trying to express that, at some point in the future, something should have been removed from a collection after a certain event happened.

The exact sentence I used for this is (it's about caching of sessions in a web application):

> This is an expired session that should have been removed from the
>   cache after a new session has been saved.

This sounds really wrong to me (not a native speaker), especially the *should have been*. If I use it like this, it sounds like I want to express that the session won't be saved even though it is supposed to.

Now my question is: Do we use Future II like this? And does it only sound strange to me because I'm not used to it, or because I have misunderstood something completely?

Also, if so, I'd be happy if someone could rephrase this sentence for me, as I also have the feeling that I might have messed up the tenses in it completely anyway.

Comment: Futur II is the German term for the future perfect: _I will have arrived._ Is this what you mean? Your example looks more like Konjunktiv II if it were in German.

Comment: No, I want to express a passive future perfect. Konjunktiv is exactly what I don't want it to look like, even though I agree, that it does. Which is why I asked the question.

Comment: If all you mean is that the cache will be emptied after a document save, then you can express that in the present or future. I don't understand why you need future perfect. What you have now is an unreal condition: the cache should have been emptied but wasn't.

Comment: But that's not all I want to say. It's about the very fact that the session exists at the moment, but SHOULD (if everything goes as planned) at any given point in the future, after a new session has been saved, have been removed by another process.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't say: *should be removed from the cache after a new session has been saved*. Or *should be removed from the cache by the time a new session is saved.* Why can't you use plain future rather than future perfect?

Comment: I agree, that there might be an easier ways to say this and I have changed the sentence accordingly in the meantime. I'd still be interested in knowing whether my abomination is grammatically correct in theory though.

Comment: I don't think you can put either *should have been* or *is supposed to have been* in the future. Which makes it really difficult to write your original sentence grammatically. The best I can come up with is *"... an expired session that, if everything works properly, will have been removed from the cache by the time ..."*

Comment: What is the "Future II"? Please [edit] this to explain.

Comment: @I would second Peter Shor.

Answer (score -3):

The problem with your sentence is the last clause. It should read

"This is an expired session that should have been removed from the cache after a new session was saved."